# Проблема с методом

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте. При изучении java и Android столкнулся с проблемой вызова метода из другого класса. Пытаюсь написать живые обои, создал два класса LiveWorld и LivePaint, хочу из класса LivePaint вызвать метод но при тестировании на самом устройстве выдаётся ошибка приложения.

Вот отрывок кода вызова метода из класса LiveWorld:

```
public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onVisibilityChanged(visible);
    LivePaint painting = new LivePaint();
    mVisible = visible;
    if (visible){
        painting.Paint(c, context);
    }
}
```

Вот вызываемый метод из класса LivePaint:

```
public void Paint (Canvas c, Context context){
    rectangle = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.rectangle);
    try{
        c = this.holder.lockCanvas();
        c.drawBitmap(rectangle, 300, 150, null);
    }
    finally{
        this.holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
    }
}
```

В логе он ругается на вызов метода painting.Paint(c, context).
По пробовал написать весь программный код в одном классе, всё работает.
Подскажите пожалуйста в чём может быть ошибка.

[image]

Comment: Как конкретно он ругается на вызов метода painting.Paint(c, context)? Приложите к вопросу стектрейс.

Comment: Я извиняюсь, ещё не понял, как работает ваш редактор. Вроде HTML тэги прописываю, а оказывается не правильно. :)

Comment: Да, он ругается на вызов метода painting.Paint(c, context).
Смысл пользоваться стектрейс, если полный код без вызова метода работает правильно, а вот когда эти действия добавляю в метод отдельного класса выдаётся ошибка.

Comment: Добавьте:

    public void Paint (Canvas c, Context context){
        if( this.holder == null ) {
            throw new IllegalStateException( "Holder is not initialized");
        }
    //...

Comment: Добавил, в логе вроде ничего не пишет

Comment: Короче забросил я идею с методами в разных классах и реализовал всё в одном. Спасибо всем тем, кто пытался помочь.

Comment: Что конкретно Вы использовали при передачу Context?

Answer (score 1):

Да, действительно была проблема с контекстом. Надо было так написать:
painting.Paint(c, LiveWorld.this, holder);